# How can I install Internet Explorer 7 on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you install MSIE7 in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/33496/how-do-you-install-msie7-in-windows-7)

I need to install Internet Explorer 7 on my Windows 7 machine.
How can this be done?

Comment: What additional/alternative functionality do you need from installing IE7?  I only ask as there may be an easier workaround.

Comment: I assume the asker needs IE7 for web application testing purposes... right?

Comment: I couldn't see any other reason. IE8 has better standards capabilities, IE6 has been standardized on by many lazy developers, but IE7 is the red-headed stepchild of the Trident engine family.

Comment: I'm a web developer and need to run tesst on every browser. that's one good reason

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can't install Internet Explorer 7 but you can run it inside Internet Explorer 8 (as the rendering engine is bundled) by doing the following (NOTE: This method also works in IE 9):

1. Open IE8
2. Open >Tools >Developer Tools
3. Switch Browser Mode to IE7 and Document Mode to IE7

Alternatively, you can download an installer for every Internet Explorer version from http://finalbuilds.edskes.net/iecollection.htm

Comment: This is so cool. now I can also use its superb (relatively speaking) developer debugger

Comment: Just to point out IE 6 does not work correctly on Vista, so is unlikely to work correctly on Windows 7.

Comment: We're in the same boat; unfortunately we've found differences between "real" IE7 and IE8 with DocMode set to IE7, so we've got with multiple VMs.

Comment: As StevenV said, there are considerable differences. I came here looking for a solution to this question precisely because things were running fine in IE9 with 7's browser and docmode but the actual IE7 was crashing completely.

Answer (score 10):

You can't install it natively since Internet Explorer 8 is already part of Windows 7. But you can use the [Virtual PC Image](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en) supplied by Microsoft for that purpose.

Another option would be to install Internet Explorer 7 within the Virtual XP mode, provided you have at least Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: I do have Windows 7 Professional version. 
I'm a web developer, And working from my computer localhost,
so i think that Virtual PC might be a problem for me.

Comment: Where would Virtual PC be a problem for you? I don't quite see it.

Comment: virtual PC is an insulated environment, how can it access it's parent computers' localhost server ?

Comment: You can very likely still access the host computer by name. Just because the VM runs on the host system doens't mean they can't share a network ...

Comment: from the readme.txt: "This image will expire on February 14, 2013"

Answer (score 1):

While you can't install IE7 on a Windows 7 machine, there's a program called [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) which provides historical versions of the Trident rendering engine (the core of Internet Explorer). IE7 is included as one of those historical versions, so you'll be able to evaluate how a site renders, without needing to actually run IE7 itself.

Comment: I've found IETester to be extremely inconsistent in both rendering and JS bugs relative to the actual browsers it purports to let you test, which in my opinion is not a useful test.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Chris Charabaruk's [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/32327/how-can-i-install-ie7-on-windows-7/32351#32351), there's also something called [MultipleIEs](http://tredosoft.com/multipleIEs), which accomplishes the same.

Comment: yes I was using this program ever since it got out, but no more, because I've stopped supporting IE6 :) good program.