# Interface is unknown after installing Internet Explorer 7 standalone on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer-7

Yesterday, I tried installing [Internet Explorer 7 standalone](http://tredosoft.com/IE7_standalone) on Windows 7. I didn't get any installation problems though I started facing weird errors.

When I open Windows Explorer an error appeared in the title bar:

> The interface is unknown with "explorer.exe"

I tried re-registering a number of DLLs such as `actxprxy.dll`, `shdocvw.dll` and so on as listed [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281679).

I can now open Windows Explorer but I am unable to copy/paste and many other operations no longer work.

What should I do? How can I fix this?

Comment: I can not do operations like Copy and Pasting of files, manage another user account, parental control etc

Answer (score 1):

IE7 is not present on Windows 7.  The OS shipped with IE8 native.

However, you can enable [IE7 developer mode](https://superuser.com/questions/32327/how-can-i-install-internet-explorer-7-on-windows-7) in Windows 7, although I should think running XP Mode would work better as you could then test IE6 and IE7.

Comment: My problem is I can not do operations like Copy and Pasting of files, manage another user account, parental control etc. because of ie7s. I want to get rid of that.